# Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by itself in preflight response

Tags: express, cors, meanjs

I have come across CORS issues multiple times and can usually fix it but I want to really understand by seeing this from a MEAN stack paradigm.

Before I simply added middleware in my express server to catch these things, but it looks like there is some kind of pre-hook that is erroring out my requests.

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

I assumed that I could do this:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*")
})
```

or the equivalent but this doesn't seem to fix it. I also of course tried

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Headers")
})
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

When you start playing around with custom request headers you will get a CORS preflight. This is a request that uses the HTTP `OPTIONS` verb and includes several headers, one of which being `Access-Control-Request-Headers` listing the headers the client wants to include in the request.

You need to reply to that CORS preflight with the appropriate CORS headers to make this work. One of which is indeed `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. That header needs to contain the same values the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header contained (or more).

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol explains this setup in more detail.

Comment: If you using Chrome and your not sure what headers are being requested, use the Developer Console, Network select the call being made and you can view what headers are being requested by `Access-Control-Request-Headers`

Comment: The Developer Console option is a good one. You can also find what you need by getting access to the request object on the server and dumping the values for the headers, but specifically the header value for "Access-Control-Request-Headers". Then, copy/paste this into your response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "{paste here}")

Comment: example please!

Comment: @Demodave an example of this for me was `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type")`

Comment: @LionelMorrison, use of chrome dev tools for matching headers.  well explained !!!

Comment: I'd read a lot of "explanations" until I found yours!! everybody suggest using `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` but it's `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, authorization');` what did the trick for me!

Comment: Well, you need `-Methods` for HTTP methods, such as `POST` and `PUT`, and `-Headers` for HTTP headers, such as `Authorization`...

Comment: I understand the answer, but I don't understand why we need to explicitely allow a client to send headers to a server... I guess it's a security measure, but I don't get the purpose of this. If a server doesn't handle unexpected headers, it just won't use those. If anyone can edit to explain the purpose of this "limitation", that'd be even better!

Comment: If all servers were written in the way you suggest, that'd be true, but that's not the case.

Comment: Checking the actual request headers using Chrome console was amazing advice! I think the big thing is that if you're working with unusual environments like Node+React microservice front end with AWS lambda backend, there are additional AMZ headers!

Comment: Another method for checking `Request Headers` (And Network, Response Headers, Response Body) is by using Postman's app console. Everything is there.

Comment: Get Postman desktop app, and at the bottom of the app you'll see the console icon. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278422/7389293

Answer (score 205):

This is what you need to add to make it work.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

The browser sends a preflight request (with method type OPTIONS) to check if the service hosted on the server is allowed to be accessed from the browser on a different domain. In response to the preflight request if you inject above headers the browser understands that it is ok to make further calls and i will get a valid response to my actual GET/POST call. you can constraint the domain to which access is granted by using Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost, xvz.com" instead of * . ( * will grant access to all domains)

Comment: You cannot combine `*` for `...-Origin` and `true` for `...-Credentials`. It will not fail for non-credentialed requests, but it will not work for credentialed requests either. See the link I posted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Manish Arora, I used your solution in my api and it worked.

 HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");

Comment: This is saying server side all this response header munging is necessary because of "preflight"?  Why?  Especially for perfectly standard headers?  Having used HTTP for a while it is news to me that so much boilerplate is needed.

Comment: @manish I had a different set of values for Access-Control-Allow-Headers that didn't work. Your set of values did. Thanks for saving time and frustration.

Comment: Is there a way to wildcard some headers? Is it a bad idea to wildcard all headers? Such as `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")`? What's the security implication of doing this?

Comment: I had the wildcard set and that didn't work. For the above solution to work, I had to add "Authorization" to the list. Now it's good.

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins Because the origins of the client and the server are different. You can't just let a website request some random server for security reasons.

Answer (score 135):

This problem solved with

```
 "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
```

Particular in my project (express.js/nodejs)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

Update:

Every time error: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by itself in preflight response` error you can see what wrong with [chrome developer tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools):
[image]

above error is missing `Content-Type` so add string `Content-Type` to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Comment: This won't work for everyone. The value for Access-Control-Request-Headers may vary based upon environment. Get access to the request object on the server and dump the values for the "Access-Control-Request-Headers" header. Then, copy/paste this into your response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "{paste here}")

Comment: Also make sure you're spelling Authorization the american way not the Britsh way. That's half an hour of my life I won't get back. Thx USA! [sigh]

Comment: Worked for me, sinced I used Authorization in my request headers, thanks !

Comment: This is wht i have been looking for a long time

Comment: Because [`Origin` is a request header that only the browser (not the client) can set](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header), you never need to list that name in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header.

Comment: this line was the most helpful line: `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");` I was scoring SO for a solution.

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer is ok, but I had difficulties to understand it. So here is a simple example to clarify it.

In my ajax request I had a standard Authorization header.

```
$$(document).on('ajaxStart', function(e){
var auth_token = localStorage.getItem(SB_TOKEN_MOBILE);
if( auth_token ) {
    var xhr = e.detail.xhr;

    xhr.setRequestHeader('**Authorization**', 'Bearer ' + auth_token);
}
```

This code produces the error in the question. What I had to do in my nodejs server was to add Authorization in allowed headers:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,**Authorization**');
```

Answer (score 15):

Just to add that you can put those headers also to Webpack config file. I needed them as in my case as I was running webpack dev server.

```
devServer: {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 13):

To add to the other answers. I had the same problem and this is the code i used in my express server to allow REST calls:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'URLs to trust of allow');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
  res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

What this code basically does is intercepts all the requests and adds the CORS headers, then continue with my normal routes. When there is a OPTIONS request it responds only with the CORS headers.

EDIT: I was using this fix for two separate nodejs express servers on the same machine. In the end I fixed the problem with a simple proxy server.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on how you used a simple proxy server?

Comment: @austin_ce "a simple proxy server" could look like this in express:

/* Luke Kroon's Code Here */

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { url, options } = req.body;
  try {
    await fetch(url, options || undefined);
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch {
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  }
});

Comment: and then in your front-end, replace "fetch" with this function:

async function proxyFetch(url, options = undefined) {
        const res = await fetch(localHost, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ url, options }),
        });
        return res.status;
      }

Answer (score 7):

res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this issue myself, in the context of ASP.NET make sure your Web.config looks like this:

```
  <system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>

<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <!--<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>-->
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <!--
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  -->
</handlers>

<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Notice the Authorization value for the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` key. I was missing the Authorization value, this config solves my issue.

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome:

> Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

For me, this error was triggered by **a trailing space** in the URL of this call.

```
jQuery.getJSON( url, function( response, status, xhr ) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Very good i used this on a silex project

```
$app->after(function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
        $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 5):

this problem occurs when we make custom header for request.This request that uses the `HTTP OPTIONS` and includes several headers.

The required header for this request is **`Access-Control-Request-Headers`** , which should be part of response header and should allow request from all the origin. Sometimes it needs `Content-Type` as well in header of response. So your response header should be like that -

```
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // allow request from all origin
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
```

Answer (score 5):

I received the error the OP stated using Django, React, and the django-cors-headers lib.  To fix it with this stack, do the following:

In settings.py add the below per the [official documentation](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/).

```
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + (
'YOUR_HEADER_NAME',
)
```

Comment: exactly what I needed !!!

Answer (score 5):

After spending almost a day, I just found out that adding the below two codes solved my issue.

Add this in the Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
  if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
  {
    Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;             
    Response.End();
  }
}
```

and in the web config add the below

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />        
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to add a custom header on the request headers, you have to let the server know that specific header is allowed to take place. The place to do that is in the class that filters the requests. In the example shown below, the custom header name is "type":

```js
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, Authorization, type ");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Authorization");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add this headers into your ajax or js function

```
headers: {
            "Cache-Control": null,
            "X-Requested-With": null,
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Message is clear that 'Authorization' is not allowed in API. Set
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type, Authorization"

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same problem in Angular 6. I solved the issue by using below code. Add the code in component.ts file.

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

headers;

constructor() {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
}

getData() {
    this.http.get(url,this.headers). subscribe (res => {
    // your code here...
})}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Post API call we are sending data in request body. So if we will send data by adding any extra header to an API call. Then first OPTIONS API call will happen and then post call will happen. Therefore, you have to handle OPTION API call first.

You can handle the issue by writing a filter and inside that you have to check for option call API call and return a 200 OK status. Below is the sample code:

```
package com.web.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;

public class CustomFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
        if (httpRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {
            response.setStatus(Response.SC_OK);
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        // TODO
    }

    public void destroy() {
        // Todo
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're configuring an AWS API Gateway (for example, that's sending the request from a React AWS Amplify app), the solution is to append the string

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

to the Access-Control-Allow-Headers field in the Enable CORS dialog fpr the given endpoint & method:

[image: API Gateway Enable Cors]

...and then deploy the API:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.get('/with-cors', cors(), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ msg: 'WHOAH with CORS it works!  ' })
})
```

Adding cors in get function Is what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issues when trying to connect to a Django backend:

> Request header field authorisation is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

After hours of searching, I finally resolved it with the help of the following comment:

> Also make sure you're spelling Authorization the american way not the Britsh way. That's half an hour of my life I won't get back. Thx USA! [sigh]

So a hint for someone else who is stuck: check that you are spelling the word "Authorization" correctly. If you set the Access-Control-Allow-Headers = ["Authorisation"], you are allowing the wrong header!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, which specifies which websites should be given permission for CORS where `*` is for all the websites.

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, which specifies which methods should be allowed.

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, which is used for authorization.

An example of them all implemented:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
    
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use((req,res,next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type,Authorization');
  next();
});
```

Comment: For some reason this doesnt work in.Net 6. I get the error Delegate 'Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task>' does not take 3 arguments

Answer (score 0):

That same issue i was facing.

I did a simple change.

```
  <modulename>.config(function($httpProvider){
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Use this i was also facing issue while integrating in angular application.

Write this.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin,X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PATCH,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  next();
});
```

Follow me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Next js My Problem got Solved using

```
const cors=micro_cors({
   origin:"https://studio.apollographql.com",
   allowMethods:['POST','GET','PUT','PATCH','DELETE','OPTIONS'],
   allowCredentials:true,
   allowHeaders:['X-Requested-With','X-HTTP-Method-Override','Content-Type','Authorization','Accept','Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ]
})
```

then wapping it in

```
 export default cors(async function handler(req, res) {
   await serverStart
   if(req.method==="OPTIONS"){
    res.end()
     return false
   }
     apolloserver.createHandler({path:"/api/graphql"})(req,res)

 })
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure all headers you require from client is passed to to Access-Control-Allow-Headers, else you'll keep running into CORS issues. In this case, that would be 'x-api-key' else you keep running into cors issues

```
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: new Headers({
    "X-API-Key": "ds67GHjkshjh00ZZhhsskhjgasHJHJHJ&87",
  }),
};

response.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
    "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, x-api-key");
```

Answer (score -2):

I just added `response.headers;` after

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(
          api + "api/users/all",
        ),
      );
```

The CORS setup in the backend(Django) as official documentation,
[Djnago-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers)