# How to remove authorization header from request

Tags: angularjs, jwt, cloudinary

I'm using [MEAN Stack User Registration and Login Example & Tutorial](https://github.com/cornflourblue/mean-stack-registration-login-example%22MEAN%20Stack%20User%20Registration%20and%20Login%20Example%20&%20Tutorial%22) as the base for my app. It adds an auth header to every request in the run function:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + $window.jwtToken;
```

I want to upload images to Cloudinary but I'm getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/xxxx/upload. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

How can I remove this header specifically for requests to Cloudinary?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will require an interceptor that checks for the url of the request and clears the header if it matches. alternatively you can use the `$http` config parameter.

Using the parameter:

```
$http.post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/' + someId + '/upload', data, { headers: {} });
```

Using an interceptor:

```
.factory('cloudinaryInterceptor', function() {
 return {
  request: function(config){
   //Check for the host
   var regex = /api\.cloudinary\.com/i;
   if(regex.test(config.url))
    //Detach the header
    delete config.headers.authorization;
   return config;
  }
 }
});
```

Remember to push the interceptor in the config phase

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('cloudinaryInterceptor');
```

Answer (score -1):

This question has been asked before. The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32501365/3199310).

> When you start playing around with custom request headers you will get a CORS preflight. This is a request that uses the HTTP OPTIONS verb and includes several headers, one of which being Access-Control-Request-Headers listing the headers the client wants to include in the request.
>
> You need to reply to that CORS preflight with the appropriate CORS
>   headers to make this work. One of which is indeed
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers. That header needs to contain the same
>   values the Access-Control-Request-Headers header contained (or more).