# Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript

I got this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://62.244.120.89:9000/api/v2/content/categories/sl_1-main/.
>   Request header field HTTP_LANGUAGE_CODE is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I found question: [Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by itself in preflight response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500073/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr)

In one answer they suggest to add response headers

> ```
> response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
> response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
> response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
> response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With,
> ```
>
> Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method,
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers");

Do I do this on server on client ?

Comment: CORS is the server.... not the client

Comment: Server has to answer to preflight request (`OPTIONS`) with all non-default details, incl. the headers that are not "CORS-safelisted request headers". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS and https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would set the response headers in the server that you are making the request to.