# Elasticsearch CORS error with ReactiveSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, cors, reactivesearch

I already have a Node/Express server setup for jwt authentication working with my Create React App. I'm using the CORS npm package and simple middleware `app.use(cors());` to solve the expected CORS related problems and its working fine.

Now I want to add Elasticsearch and [ReactiveSearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivebase.html#usage) to my React app and am trying to figure out how to overcome CORS issues with my local ES instance.

My first guess is that I need to create a separate searchRoutes.js file and implement any CORS code there needed for ES to work locally and connect with my React app?

I've been following the docs for ReactiveSearch (using http-proxy-middleware) and am not having any success... keep getting this CORS error: Failed to load http://localhost:9200/query-index/_msearch?: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Even though I believe I have implemented the CORS preflight [solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight)

```
app.options('/autocomplete', cors()); // this is for pre-flight
```

Any suggestions, links, or tutorials are welcomed

UPDATE: this is my Nodejs index.js (server)

```
require('dotenv').config();
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';
import cors from 'cors';
import compression from 'compression';

// import dotenv from 'dotenv'; // added
import router from './router';
// import { dbConfig } from './config';

// Express app init
const app = express();
// app.options('/query-index', cors()); // this is for pre-flight

/* This is where we specify options for the http-proxy-middleware
 * We set the target to appbase.io backend here. You can also
 * add your own backend url here */
const options = {
    // target: 'https://scalr.api.appbase.io/',
    target: 'http://localhost:9200',
    changeOrigin: true,
    // onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req) => {
    //     proxyReq.setHeader(
    //         'Authorization',
    //         `Basic ${btoa('cf7QByt5e:d2d60548-82a9-43cc-8b40-93cbbe75c34c')}`
    //     );
    //     /* transform the req body back from text */
    //     const { body } = req;
    //     if (body) {
    //         if (typeof body === 'object') {
    //             proxyReq.write(JSON.stringify(body));
    //         } else {
    //             proxyReq.write(body);
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
};

// Connect MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

// middleware
app.use(compression());
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(cors()); // cors middleware
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/38345853/3125823
// Enable CORS from client-side from slatepeak
// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3333', 'http://localhost:9200'); // this can also be a list of urls
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, PUT, GET, POST, DELETE');
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials');
//   // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
//   next();
// });
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: '*/*' }));

/* This is how we can extend this logic to do extra stuff before
 * sending requests to our backend for example doing verification
 * of access tokens or performing some other task */
app.use('/query-index', (req, res, next) => {
    const { body } = req;
    console.log('Verifying requests ✔', body);
    /* After this we call next to tell express to proceed
     * to the next middleware function which happens to be our
     * proxy middleware */
    next();
});

/* Here we proxy all the requests from reactivesearch to our backend */
app.use('/query-index', proxy(options));

app.options('/query-index', cors()); // this is for pre-flight
app.get('/query-index', cors(), function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for route \/query-index'});
});

router(app);

const authPort = process.env.PORT || 3333; // default
const authServer = http.createServer(app);
authServer.listen(authPort);
console.log('Auth Server listening on:', authPort);
```

Comment: Could you post more code or a repo link? It should work imo, here are the [client](https://github.com/appbaseio-apps/reactivesearch-proxy-client) and [server](https://github.com/appbaseio-apps/reactivesearch-proxy-server) examples just in case

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani - I should also be able to make this work with npm cors package right? Not just http-proxy-middleware.

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani - just posted my entire index.js for Nodejs, includes the CORS and http-proxy-middleware code, please have a look at show me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani - if I put the proper CORS settings in my local ES do I still need to use a package like CORS from npm or http-proxy-middleware to get ES and ReativeSearch talking to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you could just get rid of it and plain and simple enable CORS for all requests:

```
app.use(cors())
```

Let's assume you still want to go single-route: Your code refers to a route "autocomplete", the link you posted which returns a CORS error, is referring to a different route "query_index/..", since you chose to go single-route enabling way, you need to fix this and use the matching route where you enabled CORS.

From what you've posted your solution looks furthermore incomplete.
If you look at [solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight):

```
app.get('/products/:id', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a Single Route'})
})
```

and compare it to yours, you should add a callback to your route, because the callback is where your logic happens (transfer to controller etc.).
This could look like so:

```
app.get('/autocomplete', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for route \/autocomplete'})
})
```

Comment: I think I'm seeing what your saying. Yea, /autocomplete is a client side route and runs on port 3000, ES is backend on 9200. Just need to tweak the routing a bit with CORS config. Fresh pair of eyes on the problem - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
http.cors.allow-origin: '*'
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Accept
```

You need to add these cors permissions into your elasticsearch.yml config file