# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource while accessing a local server by angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, http-headers, angular-http

I was trying to get results from a local server. The class which I am using in the service is as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class GridSearchService {

  server = 'http://127.0.0.1:8100';
  searchURL = this.server + '/yacy/grid/mcp/index/yacysearch.json?query=';
  constructor(private http: Http,
              private jsonp: Jsonp,
              private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
  }

  getSearchResults(searchquery) {


    return this.http
      .get(this.searchURL+searchquery).map(res =>
          res.json()
      ).catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

but I was getting this error in console

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8100/yacy/grid/mcp/index/yacysearch.json?query=india: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Then I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228330/7407321 and set headers accordingly. The new code looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class GridSearchService {

  server = 'http://127.0.0.1:8100';
  searchURL = this.server + '/yacy/grid/mcp/index/yacysearch.json?query=';

  constructor(private http: Http,
              private jsonp: Jsonp,
              private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
  }

  getSearchResults(searchquery) {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();

    params.set('query',searchquery);


    let headers = new Headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
                                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true",
                                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
                                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, search: params });

    return this.http
      .get(this.searchURL,options).map(res =>
          res.json()
      ).catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

I get this error message now:

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8100/yacy/grid/mcp/index/yacysearch.json?query=&query=india: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Using a CORS plugin is working fine but can it be done without that.

Comment: You don't set those headers on the client; you set them on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the server the server `http://127.0.0.1:8100/` from the client `http://localhost:4200`, the error is telling you that there is a high risk of intrusion. You can handle this from client side or from server side, by telling the server to accept request from all domains. This can be done by adding these line to your web.xml

This example is for Tomcat starting from Tomcat version 7.0.41.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern> /* </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

By default CORS headers will be set like the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (any domain)
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:  (Non-simple headers are not exposed by default)
```