# Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: angular, cors, jersey, http-headers

I'm using Angular in the frontend and Jersey for backend. I am getting an exception when I execute my PUT request. This is the Angular code:

```ts
const header=new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
header.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
header.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin");

return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080',home,{headers: header})
    .pipe(map((response: Response)=>{return response.json();}));
```

This is my filter in Jersey:

```java
@Provider
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {

        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        //headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://podcastpedia.org"); podcastpedia.org       
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS");          
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"); 
    }

}
```

This is the exception:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8080/ Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Anyone can help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32500073/1531971

Comment: @jdv is not the correct answer because I need to resolve "Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Methods "

Comment: You need to be clear about how this Q&A about this exact same message you report is not relevant as part of your research. See [ask], but it is your responsibility to do some basic research, including any other Q&A, and tell us how they do not apply in this case. This should be in the text of the question via an [edit].

Comment: This is the right answer to your question, angular try to perform an options request but your server doesn’t provide right headers for this kind of requests...

Comment: @JohnnyAW which are the correct header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` from the `HttpHeaders` in the frontend code. These headers are supposed be sent as *response* headers from the server (which is what you are doing in your `CORSResponseFilter`).

> Failed to load http://localhost:8080/ Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

What this error is saying is that the server response header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` doesn't include `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` in the header value (which is shouldn't). The purpose of the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is to tell the browser which request headers the client is allowed to send to the server. You can see in the `CORSResponseFilter` which headers you allow. `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` is not one of them.

And while your at it, you might as well remove all the `Access-Control-XX-XX` values in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header. These are not required. You are saying that client can send these request headers, which it shouldn't be doing.

**See also:**

- Check out [the update in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067653/2587435) for a good explanation about how these headers work (if you are interested).