# Getting CORS error after allowing Origins

Tags: javascript, python, cors, fetch-api

My frontend and backend services are in different origins, hence problem with CORS, but in my backend (Python fastAPI) I have already added allow all origins:

```py
api.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origin_regex=".*",
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

This is how my frontend is making the call

```js
fetch('https://someurl.com/call', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Signature': btoa('0000')
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({

        })
    }).then(res => {
        return res.json()
    })
```

Error that I am getting:

> Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/call' from origin 'https://frontend.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field signature is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Is there something I am missing? Is my custom header `'Signature': btoa('0000')` the problem?

I am trying to debug, this is what I am getting from the browser console
[image]

Comment: Nothing [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Request+header+field+is+not+allowed+by+Access-Control-Allow-Headers+in+preflight+response.+site:stackoverflow.com)? - it likely is the Signature but you allow all headers so weird

Comment: Are you running it on localhost?

Comment: @Hekmatyar No, its deployed.

Comment: @mplungjan Its the Signature header causing the issue according to the console (I included screenshot)

Comment: So * is not enough it seems. Try adding the headers you allow including signature

Comment: Maybe look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests according to your error it seems you'll work with preflight request

Comment: you're not behind a reverse proxy are you?  What happens if the header is added explicitly?  This *might* just be bug to file against the middleware

Comment: @2e0byo Adding the header explicitly, definitely did something. If you see the screenshot above, I get 2 requests blocked. Now its 1. My services are hosted in google cloud, idk if i need to set something there as well.

Comment: Is [this](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/develop/adding-cors-support-api-proxy) relevant?  I have no experience with google cloud, sadly.  Your fastapi configuration looks right to me.  What happens in local?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500073/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr this maybe also could help