# CORS Errors TestCafe Mock After Upgrade

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I recently upgraded TestCafe on a project from `1.8.6` to `2.4.0` and now our mocks are failing due to CORS errors, however, I'm not sure how to resolve them. For the "OPTIONS" request I get the proper 200 status but the actual request is failing with a CORS error.

Here is the mock we use:

```
export function detailsMock(detailsMockData = {}) {
  return RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo(
      new RegExp(
        `^${env.API_URL}/orders/[0-9]+/disbursements/[0-9]+[\?disbursementId=[0-9]+]?$`
      )
    )
    .respond(detailsMockData, 200, {
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-origin': `${env.BASE_URL}`
    });
}
```

**And then in the test I have:**

```
 await t.addRequestHooks(detailsMock(detailsMockData))
 await t.navigateTo(`${env.BASE_URL}/order/${orderData.fileId}/disbursements/123`)
    .expect(viewDisbursementPageSelectors.wireNotMatchToast.innerText)
    .eql(
      'Some message.'
    )
  await t.removeRequestHooks(disbursementListMock());
```

**Here is the CORS error I'm seeing in the browser console:**

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:54392/QrHot6VR5*HJPHVnKYb!a!0!s*REMOVED-FOR-CONFIDENTIALITY/https://REMOVED-FOR-CONFIDENTIALITY/ncs/v1/orders/50612391/disbursements/123' from origin 'http://localhost:54391' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field pragma is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, to solve this issue I had to add the `g` flag to the RegExp. I think the issue was that it was only matching the first one, but with the `g` flag it matches all. I'm not sure why this changed between TestCafe versions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like mocked requests in the application tested were changed.
You need to create a separate mock for the `OPTIONS` request.
See which headers should be specified for this mock in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500073/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr) thread.