origin url has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response
has anyone ever had this problem?
When I deply my laravel application normally, it works well and I don't get no cors error.
but when I deploy using CI/CD, I always get cors error, I've done everything right, even created custom middleware to handle cors but no way.
I am using Docker to build
I am using zeabur for CI/CD if you've heard of it. please help, I'm stuck and confused.
I created custom middleware and a custom .conf configuration on the server and I was expecting it to work as long as I had allowed and set my origin

I don't know nothing about zeabur, but reading your error message it seems that your server response doesn't have an  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

thank you for your response but below is my code from cors.php
'paths' => ['api/'],
'allowed_methods' => ['POST', 'GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS'],
'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:5173'],
'allowed_headers' => [':authority:', ':method:', ':path:', ':scheme:',''],
'allow_headers' => [
'Content-Type',
'X-Auth-Token',
'Origin',
'Authorization',
'X-Requested-With',
'Accept'
],
'max_age' => 0,


Please edit your question to include the code in a readable format. Or, see if this can be used to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500073/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr
